# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Using the below shown Code I receive an error in this line (this line is at the bottom of the below full code snippet):

```
address: data['address'] ??
```

I can get my head around what this could mean or caused this. Has anyone an idea?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:keekz_mvp/config/paths.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:keekz_mvp/models/models.dart';

class Keekz extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final User author;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String caption;
  final int likes;
  final DateTime date;
  final GeoPoint location;
  final Map<String, String> address;

  const Keekz({
    this.id,
    @required this.author,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    @required this.caption,
    @required this.likes,
    @required this.date,
    @required this.location,
    @required this.address,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        id,
        author,
        imageUrl,
        caption,
        likes,
        date,
        location,
        address,
      ];

  Keekz copyWith({
    String id,
    User author,
    String imageUrl,
    String caption,
    int likes,
    DateTime date,
    GeoPoint location,
    Map<String, String> address,
  }) {
    return Keekz(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      author: author ?? this.author,
      imageUrl: imageUrl ?? this.imageUrl,
      caption: caption ?? this.caption,
      likes: likes ?? this.likes,
      date: date ?? this.date,
      location: location ?? this.location,
      address: address ?? this.address,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toDocument() {
    return {
      'author':
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(Paths.users).doc(author.id),
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
      'caption': caption,
      'likes': likes,
      'date': Timestamp.fromDate(date),
      'location': location,
      'address': address,
    };
  }

  static Future<Keekz> fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    if (doc == null) return null;
    final data = doc.data();
    final authorRef = data['author'] as DocumentReference;
    if (authorRef != null) {
      final authorDoc = await authorRef.get();
      if (authorDoc.exists) {
        return Keekz(
          id: doc.id,
          author: User.fromDocument(authorDoc),
          imageUrl: data['imageUrl'] ?? '',
          caption: data['caption'] ?? '',
          likes: (data['likes'] ?? 0).toInt(),
          date: (data['date'] as Timestamp)?.toDate(),
          location: data['location'] ?? GeoPoint(0, 0),
          address: data['address'] ??
              {
                'city': 'not set',
                'postalcode': 'not set',
                'country': 'not set'
              },
        );
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because a Map <String, dynamic> is waiting and you have a Map <String, String> defined in Address.

You must replace the data type in the address variables, it should be as follows:

`Map <String, dynamic> address;`

Comment: Thank you. Unfotunatelly I now receive this error: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: @SRel I need more information, just to be sure, you replaced in the definition of the variable to final Map <String, dynamic> and also in "Keekz copyWith" because there is also a similar value there.

In addition to this, you can provide more information about the error, what information you specifically consume, etc.

Comment: Recompiling the code onna different machine and reinstall the .apk vanishes the problem. But I do not know exactly why.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that address is expecting a map of type <String,String>, but it is receiving a map of type <String, dynamic>

Thus, change this on line #9 of your code:

`final Map<String, String> address;`

into this:

`final Map<String, dynamic> address;`

And it means that your `data['address']` isn't returning null, otherwise it would have been assigned the default string value of `not set` , but in fact, `data['address']` is returning a map of type `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`.

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Unfotunatelly I now receive this error: `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`

Comment: You most likely did not do as instructed and perhaps used cast `as String`. Because now it's comparing String to Map<String, dynamic>, which wasn't the case in the start.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. To be honest I do not know why, but I compiled the code using a complete different machine and reinstall the .apk due to the different fingerprint. The code above now works using just a map<dynamic, dynamic> which did not work beforehand either. I do not know what exactly causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this;

```
address: data['address']!=null ? jsonDecode(data['address']) :
```

i think the data come from firebase that is converted into string,.. so it need to jsondecode bfore use it as Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: You don't need to json.Decode data from firebase. The returned values are already decoded.